# Unfortunately app has stopped in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to Android and I am trying a few small apps (like Compass). When I run the app in the emulator, it gives the message `Unfortunately, Compass has Stopped`.

I have no compile time errors.

How do I solve this, and what is causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the logcat say? If you don't know how to use it see http://www.appaholics.in/using-the-logcat

Comment: What is the Compass application?

Comment: I have the same issue: Every App closes with those words -.- Except from the browser. Strange

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message and found that, in commenting out uses-permission nodes in AndroidManifest.xml I had commented out one that was needed.  When I put it back in the app ran fine.  I was able to reproduce the error.  I needed:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

This was for a barebones index.html, single page app, that displays Hello World.
And the permission above was the only one I needed to do Run As/ Android Application and get it to run in an emulator.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You have posted no code so it's difficult to see what your problem is. However I had the same issue which has been sorted out here [Unfortunately HelloListView has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009030/unfortunately-hellolistview-has-stopped/)

Answer (score 2):

It probably due to the fact that you don't have accelerometer and magnetic field support.
Go to your AVD configuration and add the following hardware: `Magnetic Field Support` and `accelerometer`

Answer (score 2):

First check your **AndroidManifest.xml** file and write activity tag

For example, you have **DisplayMessageActivity.class** and package is **me.user_interface**

tag is:

```
<activity android:name="me.user_interface.DisplayMessageActivity"/>
```

You can write this after `</activity>` tag in **AndroidManifest.xml** file. Check the path carefully.