# Unfortunately HelloListView has stopped

Tags: java, android

I've followed [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) but when I try to run the application I get `Unfortunately HelloListView has stopped`
The IDE gives no warnings or errors.

My HelloViewListActivity.java looks like this:

```
public class HelloListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My strings.xml and list_item.xml are both [identical to the tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

[Logcat log here](http://pastebin.com/P0xrX2PC)
What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems your list_content_simple.xml is not proper. Verify one more time.

Comment: @thinksteep the list_content_simple.xml is not mentioned in the tutorial there. I did find it out the SDK folders and added it to my res/layout but still same error.

Comment: The tutorial you are referring is little bit fragmented. See my answer now. I have included link for working example tutorial, you may ignore database part if you don't want.

Comment: Use [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) to get more information about a crash.  Or on a device, use the Catlog app from the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)` after the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

the `R.layout.yourlayout` should look like this ( in folder res/layout ) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView 
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding the ListView within a LinearLayout fixed my issue. It's just strange that in 2 tutorials I followed none of them mention this step.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend ListActivity, you need to have an xml which contains id as `@android:id/list`, then in your activity you need to  `setContentView(R.layout.yourxmlName)`; Here is [tutorial](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/).

Comment: When I have a ListActivity I must always have something with '@android:id/list' ? Can I not change ID to anything else like '@android:id/list2' ?

Comment: no, if you want to use a custom list ( or a custom id ), you have to use an `Activity` instead of a `ListActivity`, and then get the list with a `findViewById(R.id.thelistid)`